# Python split('=') not behaving as expected

Tags: python

I have a txt file named 'a.txt' with the following content:

```
    Hi=Python
```

Now, I am splitting the contents on '='...However the code given below does not behave as expected:

```
with open("j1.txt") as data:
    for line in data:
        j=line.split('=')
        if j[1]=='Python':
            print 'hi'
```

Can someone be kind enough to help in pin-pointing the error and help rectifying it.

Comment: can you add `print repr(line)` at the top of your for loop?

Comment: After adding repr(line) its giving me ' Hi=Python\n'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`j[1]` ends with newline `\n` (every line in a text file does). Strip it before:

```
j = line.rstrip().split('=')
```

Comment: rstrip() just removes the trailing characters, so what difference does it make in this case? Your answer is correct..but i fail to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: @JannatArora `'Python\n' != 'Python'`